# would it be possible to make a system that gives a role if they type in a certain channel using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Right so im trying to make a bot for a roleplay server and i want it so that when someone with the "No oc" role makes a character in character-subbmisons it gives them the "Waiting for approval" role is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on_message` event:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == 'Give Me The Role With ID 123456789': # text goes there
        role = message.guild.get_role(123456789) # role ID goes there
        await message.author.add_roles(role, reason='Bot Role')
```